# Could and could have

Tags: could-modal

What's the difference when I refer to the past?

He couldn't hear us

He couldn't have heard us

Second question
One guy told me a story and he said "and a mum wouln't let him grab sweets" is that the same as she didn't let him grab sweets?

Comment: Please ask only one question per posting.

Comment: Ok i get that sorry

Answer (score 0):

**He couldn't hear us** is a statement of fact. He was too far away / deaf or prevented from hearing us for some other reason.
**He couldn't have heard us** is speculation. The reason he did/didn't do something was that he apparently didn't hear what we said. Although he might have heard but decided to act the way he did regardless.

Comment: Thanl you so much. What about would and would have?

Comment: It works the same with: I couldn't do anything more and I couldn't have done anything more where first is a fact and second is a speculation I m not entirely sure it may be that it was possible to do something yes?

Comment: @trainbee282 In my opinion (others may rightly disagree), when speaking in the first person, **I couldn't do anything more** is still a statement of fact.  **I couldn't have done anything more** could still be a statement of fact, but there is an element of uncertainty or regret. "I couldn't have done anything more to help, but he still had an accident"